# Passar valor que clico para dentro de div popup

Tags: javascript

Quero obter o valor do dia que tenho numa tabela. Esta num hyperlink, e quando clico, passar para a div popuup, que se vai abrir com o dia impresso (variavel aff_j).

```
disp("<TD class=j bgcolor='"+colFerie+"' align='center'><a onclick='open_popup()' href='#'><FONT face='Arial' size='-1' color='"+colTexte+"'>"+aff_j+"</FONT></a></TD>");
function open_popup(){
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Div popup

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none" align="center" >
        <a onclick="close_popup()" href="#" style="float: right;">X</a>
        <br>            
        <label>POPUP</label>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, pretendes passar o valor da variável `aff_j` para dentro da tua *popup* cuja mesma é inicializada pela função `open_popup()` que por sua vez é chamada no evento `click` da tag `<a/>` presente numa tabela.

Se adicionares o valor como parâmetro:

```js
/*...*/ "onclick='open_popup(\""+aff_j+"\")'" /*...*/
```

Podes depois receber o mesmo na tua função `open_popup()`:

```js
function open_popup(aff_j) { /*...*/ }
```

Dando assim possibilidade de fazer algo com esse valor quando a *popup* abre.

## O teu código alterado:

```js
disp("<TD class=j bgcolor='"+colFerie+"' align='center'><a onclick='open_popup(\""+aff_j+"\")' href='#'><FONT face='Arial' size='-1' color='"+colTexte+"'>"+aff_j+"</FONT></a></TD>");

function open_popup(aff_j) {

    // fazer algo com o valor de "aff_j"
    alert(aff_j);

    // ...
}
```

---

## Exemplo

em baixo exemplo a funcionar mediante a estrutura apresentada na tua pergunta:

```js
function close_popup() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}

function open_popup(aff_j) {

    // fazer algo com o valor de "aff_j"
    alert("Clicou no dia: " + aff_j);
    var myPopup  = document.getElementById('popup');
    
    myPopup.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>'+aff_j+'</div>');

    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = 'block'; 
}

function disp (meuHtml) {
    document.getElementById("minhaTr").innerHTML = meuHtml;
}

// As variáveis que estás a utilizar
var colFerie = "black",
    colTexte = "white",
    aff_j    = 1;

// A chamada da tua função como tens na pergunta mas com adição do sugerido na minha resposta
disp("<TD class=j bgcolor='"+colFerie+"' align='center'><a onclick='javascript:open_popup(\""+aff_j+"\")' href='#'><FONT face='Arial' size='-1' color='"+colTexte+"'>"+aff_j+"</FONT></a></TD>");
```

```css
#abc{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dia</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="minhaTr"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="popup" style="display:none" align="center" >
    <a onclick="close_popup()" href="#" style="float: right;">X</a>
    <br/>
    <label>POPUP</label>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="abc">Eu também estava escondida!</div>
```

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/xjpwwgsn/).

Comment: O valor da me undefined.

Comment: @akm Desculpa, faltou-me o escape do valor: `"onclick='open_popup(\""+aff_j+"\")'"`. Editei para retificar a resposta.

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @akm A origem do teu problema atual deverá estar noutro lado pois o código como sugiro na resposta funciona bem. Podes ver este [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/xjpwwgsn/) onde simulo o teu ambiente.